# Logical const in a container in C++

Tags: c++, stdmap, mutable, const-iterator

Edited to include MWE (removing example-lite) and added details about compilation and Valgrind output.

I am using the mutable keyword to achieve the result of lazy evaluation and caching a result.  This works fine for a single object, but doesn't seem to work as expected for a collection.

My case is more complex, but let's say I have a triangle class that can calculate the area of a triangle and cache the result.  I use pointers in my case because the thing being lazily evaluated is a more complex class (it is actually another instance of the same class, but I'm trying to simplify this example).

I have another class that is essentially a collection of triangles.  It has a way to calculate the total area of all the contained triangles.

Logically, tri::Area() is const -- and mesh::Area() is const.  When implemented as above, Valgrind shows a memory leak (m_Area).

I believe since I am using a const_iterator, the call to tri::Area() is acting on a copy of the triangle.  Area() is called on that copy, which does the new, calculates the area, and returns the result.  At that point, the copy is lost and the memory is leaked.

In addition, I believe this means the area is not actually cached.  The next time I call Area(), it leaks more memory and does the calculation again.  Obviously, this is non-ideal.

One solution would be to make mesh::Area() non-const.  This isn't great because it needs to be called from other const methods.

I think this might work (mark m_Triangles as mutable and use a regular iterator):

However, I don't love marking m_Triangles as mutable -- I'd prefer to keep the compiler's ability to protect the constiness of m_Triangles in other un-related methods.  So, I'm tempted to use const_cast to localize the ugly to just the method that needs it.  Something like this (mistakes likely):

Not sure how to implement with const_cast -- should I be casting m_Triangles or this?  If I cast this, is m_Triangles visible (since it is private)?

Is there some other way that I'm missing?

The effect I want is to keep mesh::Area() marked const, but have calling it cause all the tris calculate and cache their m_Area.  While we're at it -- no memory leaks and Valgrind is happy.

I've found plenty of examples of using mutable in an object -- but nothing about using that object in a collection from another object.  Links to a blog post or tutorial article on this would be great.

Thanks for any help.

## Update

From this MWE, it looks like I was wrong about the point of the leak.

The code below is Valgrind-clean if the call to `SplitIndx()` is removed.

In addition, I added a simple test to confirm that the cached value is getting stored and updated in the container-stored objects.

It now appears that the call `m_Triangles[indx] = t1;` is where the leak occurs.  How should I plug this leak?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>


class point
{
public:
    point()
    {
        v[0] = v[1] = v[2] = 0.0;
    }
    point( double x, double y, double z )
    {
        v[0] = x; v[1] = y; v[2] = z;
    }
    double v[3];
    friend point midpt( const point & p1, const point & p2 );
    friend double dist( const point & p1, const point & p2 );
    friend double area( const point & p1, const point & p2, const point & p3 );
};

point midpt( const point & p1, const point & p2 )
{
    point pmid;
    pmid.v[0] = 0.5 * ( p1.v[0] + p2.v[0] );
    pmid.v[1] = 0.5 * ( p1.v[1] + p2.v[1] );
    pmid.v[2] = 0.5 * ( p1.v[2] + p2.v[2] );
    return pmid;
}

double dist( const point & p1, const point & p2 )
{
    double dx = p2.v[0] - p1.v[0];
    double dy = p2.v[1] - p1.v[1];
    double dz = p2.v[2] - p1.v[2];
    return sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz );
}

double area( const point & p1, const point & p2, const point & p3 )
{
    double a = dist( p1, p2 );
    double b = dist( p1, p3 );
    double c = dist( p2, p3 );

    // Place in increasing order a, b, c.
    if ( a < b )
    {
        std::swap( a, b );
    }
    if ( a < c )
    {
        std::swap( a, c );
    }
    if ( b < c )
    {
        std::swap( b, c );
    }

    if ( c-(a-b) < 0.0 )
    {
        // Not a real triangle.
        return 0.0;
    }

    return 0.25 * sqrt( ( a + ( b + c ) ) * ( c - ( a - b ) ) * ( c + ( a - b ) ) * ( a + ( b - c ) ) );
}

class tri
{
public:
    tri()
    {
        m_Area = NULL;
    }
    tri( const point & p1, const point & p2, const point & p3 )
    {
        m_P1 = p1; m_P2 = p2; m_P3 = p3;
        m_Area = NULL;
    }
    ~tri() {
        delete m_Area;
    }
    tri( const tri & t )
    {
        m_P1 = t.m_P1;
        m_P2 = t.m_P2;
        m_P3 = t.m_P3;
        if ( t.m_Area )
        {
            m_Area = new double( *(t.m_Area) );
        }
        else
        {
            m_Area = NULL;
        }
    }
    tri & operator=( const tri & t )
    {
        if ( this != &t )
        {
            m_P1 = t.m_P1;
            m_P2 = t.m_P2;
            m_P3 = t.m_P3;
            if ( t.m_Area )
            {
                m_Area = new double( *(t.m_Area) );
            }
            else
            {
                m_Area = NULL;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    bool KnowsArea() const
    {
        if ( !m_Area ) return false;
        return true;
    }
    void SetPts( const point & p1, const point & p2, const point & p3 )
    {
        m_P1 = p1; m_P2 = p2; m_P3 = p3;
        delete m_Area;
        m_Area = NULL;
    }
    double Area() const
    {
        if ( !m_Area )
        {
            m_Area = new double;
            *m_Area = area( m_P1, m_P2, m_P3 );
        }
        return *m_Area;
    }
    void Split( tri & t1, tri & t2 )
    {
        point p4 = midpt( m_P2, m_P3 );
        t1.SetPts( m_P1, m_P2, p4 );
        t2.SetPts( m_P1, p4, m_P3 );
    }

private:
    point m_P1;
    point m_P2;
    point m_P3;
    mutable double * m_Area;
};

class mesh
{
public:
    double Area() const
    {
        double area = 0;
        std::map<int,tri>::const_iterator it;
        for (it=m_Triangles.begin(); it!=m_Triangles.end(); ++it)
        {
            area += it->second.Area();
        }
        return area;
    }
    std::map<int, tri> m_Triangles;

    int KnownArea() const
    {
        int count = 0;
        std::map<int,tri>::const_iterator it;
        for (it=m_Triangles.begin(); it!=m_Triangles.end(); ++it)
        {
            if ( it->second.KnowsArea() ) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    void SplitIndx( int indx )
    {
        tri t1, t2;
        m_Triangles[indx].Split( t1, t2 );
        m_Triangles[indx] = t1;
        m_Triangles[m_Triangles.size()+1] = t2;
    }

    int NumTri() const
    {
        return m_Triangles.size();
    }
};



int main( void )
{
    point p1( 0, 0, 0 );
    point p2( 1, 0, 0 );
    point p3( 0, 1, 0 );
    point p4( 1, 1, 0 );
    point p5( 3, 4, 0 );

    tri t1( p1, p2, p3 );
    tri t2( p1, p2, p4 );
    tri t3( p1, p3, p4 );
    tri t4( p1, p3, p5 );
    tri t5( p1, p4, p5 );

    mesh m;
    m.m_Triangles[1] = t1;
    m.m_Triangles[2] = t2;
    m.m_Triangles[3] = t3;
    m.m_Triangles[4] = t4;
    m.m_Triangles[5] = t5;

    printf( "Known areas before total %d of %d\n", m.KnownArea(), m.NumTri() );

    double area = m.Area();

    printf( "Total area is %f\n", area );

    printf( "Known areas after total %d of %d\n", m.KnownArea(), m.NumTri() );

    printf( "Splitting\n" );

    m.SplitIndx( 3 );

    printf( "Known areas before total %d of %d\n", m.KnownArea(), m.NumTri() );

    area = m.Area();

    printf( "Total area is %f\n", area );

    printf( "Known areas after total %d of %d\n", m.KnownArea(), m.NumTri() );

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ mwe.cpp -o mwe
```

Or:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 mwe.cpp -o mwe
```

Valgrind output (from clang):

```
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full ./mwe
==231996== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==231996== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==231996== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==231996== Command: ./mwe
==231996==
Known areas before total 0 of 5
Total area is 3.500000
Known areas after total 5 of 5
Splitting
Known areas before total 4 of 6
Total area is 3.500000
Known areas after total 6 of 6
==231996==
==231996== HEAP SUMMARY:
==231996==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==231996==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 13 frees, 1,800 bytes allocated
==231996==
==231996== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==231996==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==231996==    by 0x48E3BA7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/libc++.so.1.0)
==231996==    by 0x4028A8: tri::Area() const (in /home/ramcdona/Desktop/mwe)
==231996==    by 0x401E57: mesh::Area() const (in /home/ramcdona/Desktop/mwe)
==231996==    by 0x4017A9: main (in /home/ramcdona/Desktop/mwe)
==231996==
==231996== LEAK SUMMARY:
==231996==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==231996==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==231996==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==231996==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==231996==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==231996==
==231996== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==231996== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Built with gcc, the Valgrind output was essentially the same.

Comment: please show a [mcve] where Valgrind reports a leak. The code you did post is jsut a class definition

Comment: The class definition as you've shown doesn't appear to leak. You could make it much easier on yourself by having `mutable std::unique_ptr<double> m_Area;`. A const_iterator shouldn't involve copies either, and even if it did, the copy's destructor would be called and the memory should be freed.

Comment: You say "I believe since I am using a const_iterator, the call to tri::Area() is acting on a copy of the triangle", but are you sure about that? Using a `const_iterator` to access triangles in the map should not cause any copies; if you try to access a non-const method from a const iterator, you'll get a compile error, not a silent copy.

Comment: You have a destructor for your class but no copy constructor or assignment operator. That could lead to Bad Things happening if you try to copy your class. That may or may not be related to the issue you're reporting.

Comment: `tri` doesn't respect rule of 5/3/0. the leak is unrelated to `mutable`.

Comment: Thanks All.  In particular for the confirmation that this code should not leak.  That was my original thought, but I couldn't reconcile why Valgrind is complaining.

I had avoided constructing a MWE because I thought this would convey enough to get the point across.

Since this passes the consensus smell test, I'll put in some more time constructing a MWE.

Comment: in `tri & operator=( const tri & t )`, you forgot to delete `this->m_Area` before to reset it to a new value. using raw owning pointer is error prone, prefer smart pointer or other container, here `std::optional<double>` seems good.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42.  That was it.  I will look into optional as mentioned by one of the other responders.  However, I also wanted to understand what was going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jarod42, the assignment operator as written is the source of the leak.

The cache and mutable are all working as expected.

The corrected code should read:

```
    tri & operator=( const tri & t )
    {
        if ( this != &t )
        {
            m_P1 = t.m_P1;
            m_P2 = t.m_P2;
            m_P3 = t.m_P3;
            delete m_Area;
            if ( t.m_Area )
            {
                m_Area = new double( *(t.m_Area) );
            }
            else
            {
                m_Area = NULL;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

The approach suggested by @TedLyngmo would also work.  In fact, it would avoid these sorts of problems entirely.  However, I was looking to understand why the existing code did not work.

Comment: If you don't feel the need to remove `mutable` anymore, just make the cache `mutable std::optional<double> m_Area;` (not a pointer to it). You'll get all the support you need from that - and no leaks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid making it `mutable` is to make it always point at the the data cache, which could be a `std::optional<double>`.

You'd then create and store a `std::unique_ptr<std::optional<double>>` that you keep for the `tri` object's lifetime.

Example:

```cpp
#include <memory>   // std::unique_ptr / std::make_unique
#include <optional> // std::optional

class tri {
public:
    using cache_type = std::optional<double>;

    tri() : m_Area(std::make_unique<cache_type>()) {} // create the cache

    tri(const tri& rhs) :                         // copy constructor
        m_Area(std::make_unique<cache_type>(*rhs.m_Area)),
        m_P1(rhs.m_P1), m_P2(rhs.m_P2), m_P3(rhs.m_P3)
    {}
    tri(tri&&) noexcept = default;                // move constructor
    tri& operator=(const tri& rhs) {              // copy assignment
        m_Area = std::make_unique<cache_type>(*rhs.m_Area);
        m_P1 = rhs.m_P1;
        m_P2 = rhs.m_P2;
        m_P3 = rhs.m_P3;
        return *this;
    }
    tri& operator=(tri&& rhs) noexcept = default; // move assignment

    // no user-defined destructor needed

    void SetPts(const point& p1, const point& p2, const point& p3) {
        m_P1 = p1;
        m_P2 = p2;
        m_P3 = p3;
        m_Area->reset(); // the cache is not up to date anymore
    }
    double Area() const {
        if(!*m_Area) *m_Area = CalcArea(); // set the cached value
        return m_Area->value();            // return the stored value
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<cache_type> m_Area;    // mutable not needed
    point m_P1;
    point m_P2;
    point m_P3;
    double CalcArea() const {
        // the calculation
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::optional` might be used for `cache_t`.

Comment: using (smart) pointer to hide mutation is "hacky". putting mutable in the `cache_t` seems more appropriate for me.

Comment: @Jarod42 Perhaps hacky. I don't have a strong opinion about it but OP wanted to get rid of `mutable` if I understood it correctly so I though this could help.

Comment: @Jarod42 Of course, `std::optional` is perfect for this. I replaced my own class to use that instead.

Comment: I was unaware of std::optional.  I will check that out.  Likewise, this is a good place to use a unique_ptr.  I will still try to construct a MWE with as close an approach to what I used in the OP, but this may be the way to go.

Comment: @RobMcDonald [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) was added in C++17. If you can't use C++17 or newer, you could use [`boost::optional`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). If you can't use `boost`, making a small class template for the caches (like I started out with in this answer) isn't too much work either.

Comment: After I updated my example, @Jarod42 pointed out the problem I had with my operator=().  I did not see a way to mark a comment to a question as the solution.

While I have no doubt your alternate approach could be made to work, I saw his answer as the most direct solution to my mistake.

Comment: @RobMcDonald Aha, I misunderstood the question. I thought it was about getting rid of `mutable` for the cache but I now see that you have put a big emphasis on the leak. As it happens, my suggestion solves both. It doesn't leak and gets rid of `mutable`. :-) By using a smart pointer, such as `unique_ptr`, providing a copy constructor and assignment operator becomes pretty easy (as shown above) + it supports move semantics out of the box, which your current version does not support at all.

Comment: @RobMcDonald: *"I did not see a way to mark a comment to a question as the solution"*. There are none. But feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are correct -- your more comprehensive C++17 approach (or the custom class based approach you started with) are more great solutions.  They would have prevented all these problems from ever happening.  I may look at employing these techniques in a future refactor (when I can test compilers, etc).

For now, I was looking to understand and fix the code.  My first guess at the problem (which focused on adding another layer of mutable) was wrong.  All the mutable stuff was working as intended, but the equals operator was leaking.

Comment: Call it assignment operator to differentiate it from comparison operators :-)